# Raspberry pi zero as keyboard controlled over wifi possible?

Tags: ssh, pi-zero-w, keyboard, hotspot

Hello I want to have a pi zero W create a wifi hotspot(no internet connection). I then want to connect to the wifi hotspot and ssh into the pi. From there i want it 
to  send keystrokes as a HID keyboard. I mostly just want to know if this is possible before I spend the time to make it and any tips are welcomed.

Comment: that is definitely possible .... research `pi zero gadgets`